# msbuild file system publish to another server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild

I need to do a file system publish which would go to another server. When I set it up in Visual studio the target locations is "\servername\sitename" and the target publish method is "file System". I have not been able to find a way to duplicate this using msbuild or msdeploy on the command line.

ex: msbuild UI.Web.csproj /T:Package /P:Configuration=Test /fl /flp:logfile=msbuild.log /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=pmcw50test /p:Password=password /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0

I have tried several different variations and the build works but it doesn't do the publish. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Best way I do is by setting up a new *Automating Build definition* under TFS.

You can set up [**Automating Builds with TFS Build Definitions**](http://boldradius.com/blog-post/UwOLcQEAAJV04Pl3/automating-builds-with-tfs-build) to publish you code to another server. You will need to specify the *MSBuild Arguments* then you can use:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:TransformConfigFiles=true  /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:DeployIisAppPath="" /p:MsDeployServiceUrl="" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:username= /p:password=

After setting up build definition successfully, Go to Team Explorer-> "Builds", right click on build definition and select "Queue New Build...", then it will automatically publish you code from TFS to the new server.

Comment: Unfortunetly we are not using TFS for version control. What I am trying to do is create a script to automate build from checkout to publish for QA and Production. This script must checkout the code from our version control, build, publish, create a diff file from the last build for changes, apply a version number, apply passwords to the web.config, encrypt the web.config. I have everything working except the auto publish to the other servers. Oh and this is a powershell script. Thanks.